# getting value in a dynamic string

Tags: php, string, dynamic, joomla

I have a problem.I want to get value in dynamic string its so complicated.
This is string

```
<['pritesh:name:nilesh:replace']>
```

This is dynamic string and i want to get name and replace variables values in this string.

Comment: I recommend looking up regular expressions in PHP.  It's designed for this sort of stuff, and it makes short work of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about the format of your string, but here's something to get you going.

You can use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert a string with delimiters to an array.  Then you can change a value and convert it back to a form delimited by, e.g. ":".  You do this by using [`join`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php), which is an alias for `implode`:

```
<?php
// initialize variable and print it
$s = "pritesh:name:nilesh:replace";
print("{$s}\n");

$s = explode(":", $s); // convert to array
$s[1] = "anotherName"; // change value

// convert back to foo:bar form and print
$s = join($s, ":");
print("{$s}\n");
?>
```

Putting that into a file `example.php` and running it on the command line:

```
$ php -q example.php
pritesh:name:nilesh:replace
pritesh:anotherName:nilesh:replace
```

As someone mentioned, if you need to handle more advanced formats you should learn how to use [regular expressions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$exploded = explode(':', $string);
$exploded[1] = $replacement;
$string = implode(':', $exploded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string is stored in a variable called `$string`, then:

```
$parts = explode(':', $string);

// this will mean that
// $parts[0] contains pritesh, $parts[1] = name, $parts[2] = nilesh and $parts[3] =  replace

// therefore
$name = $parts[0];
$replace = $parts[2];
```